# Filter Django queryset with multiple variables

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to pass one or many `GET` variables to filter a queryset. I have tried the following code to create a dictionary of the variables and apply the filter, but testing with two variables it appears to only be filtering on the final dictionary variables.

```
for k,v in mydict.items():
    qs = mymodel.objects.filter(**{"%s__contains" % k: v})
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new queryset in each iteration from scratch instead of chaining them. Try changing your code to:

```
qs = mymodel.objects.all()
for k, v in mydict.items():
    qs = qs.filter(**{"%s__contains" % k: v})
```